# C program doesnt handle non numeric key

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, cs50

Good evening people hope yall are doing well, i come to you all because i need some help regarding some C code i wrote, keep in mind that i just started coding in C so sorry if this question sounds dumb.

Basically I am doing the CS50 and we are writing a program that encripts messages so we first require the user for a command line argument which will be the key we will use to transform the plain text into cipher text. so basically if the user runs the command with lets say a 2 i.e: ./caesar 2 all the words he will type later will be "run" two sides.

my program works how is supposed and if the user types a letter instead of a number the program wont prompt for the users message. however, if the user runs the command line like this for example, ./caesar 8x the program will run eventhough the user typed a letter so any ideas on how to iterate thru the user command argument and if there is a letter the program should run? thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {

        int key = atoi(argv[1]);

        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 65) % 26) + 65);
            }

            else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97);
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("NO KEY\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if (argc >= 3 || argv[1] == (string) argv[1])
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT.  SOLVED**

this is how the code ended up looking, thanks @bruno for the help btw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char *endp;
        long lkey;
        int errno = 0;

        lkey = strtol(argv[1], &endp, 10);
        if ((errno != 0) || (*argv[1] == 0) || (*endp != 0) || (lkey < 0) || (((int) lkey) != lkey) || argc >= 3)

            // this statement check to see the characters on argv[1] are all digits
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        }
        else // if the argv[1] is all digits then prompts the user for a plaintext
        {
            int key = atoi(argv[1]); // converts the key into an integer

            string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
            printf("ciphertext: ");

            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)

                // goes thru each of the chars in plaintext and determines if is uppercase, lowercase or none.
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 65) % 26) + 65);

                    // it takes 65 and then sums it back to convert the character from the ASCII uppercase index and back
                }

                else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key) - 97) % 26) + 97);

                    // if the case is lower it takes 97 and then adds 97 back just to maintain the ASCII index.
                }

                else // if it not a lower case nor an uppercase, which means is a symbol then leave it like that.
                {
                    printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    else if (argc == 1) // if the user doesnt prompt a key print no key to user
    {
        printf("NO KEY\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if (argc >= 3) // if user prompts 3 or more keys into argv then prints error message regargind the usage
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't spam the C++ tag if your question is specifically about C (as you claim in the title)

Comment: in case there is no error `errno` is not reset to 0, it is only set when an error occurs to indicate it, so to make it a habit I encourage you to force `errno` to 0 before to call `strtol` even this is useless here because you do nothing before. You added `|| argc >= 3` but this is useless because you already check `argc==2` . When there is no % in the format I recommend to not use `printf` for nothing but `fputs(<str>, stdout)`, when you just want to print a newline do `putchar('\n')`

Comment: @bruno yes you are right, i took it out but didnt change the edit. i will give fputs a look. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the user runs the command line like this for example, ./caesar 8x the program will run eventhough the user typed a letter

you get the number from the program argument using `atoi`, it stops when a non-digit is reached, so the result is the same for 8 and 8x.

If the argument is not compatible with a number since the beginning, `atoi` will silently return 0, this is why `atoi` is dangerous. Anyway here you cannot be in that case thank to your test `isdigit(*argv[1])` before.

> any ideas on how to iterate thru the user command argument and if there is a letter the program should run

Probably you wanted to say *the program should **not** run*.

To check if all the argument is compatible with a number you can use `strtol` to do the conversion :

```
if (argc == 2) {
  char * endp;
  long lkey;

  errno = 0;

  lkey = strtol(argv[1], &endp, 10);
  if ((errno != 0) || (*argv[1] == 0) || (*endp != 0) ||
      (lkey < 0) || (((int) lkey) != lkey)) {
    printf("invalid argument %s\n", argv[1]);
  }
  else {
    int key = (int) lkey;

    ...
```

Because you currently use an `int` for the `key` I check if the value is compatible with an `int`, I also check it is positive because this is compatible with your use and in your version you verify the first character is a digit

Comment: thanks for your response and sorry for not using the adequate notation, I am new in C. The problem is the program should not run if the user types a letter inside the argv[1]. so if the user types ./caesar 4s the program should not run because the key was in the company of a letter

Comment: it ended up working thank you for the help and for such a fast response, i will post my code so you can check it out and if there is anything you think we can maybe fix to make it be better code it will be much appreciated!

Comment: @diego edit your question **adding** the new code at its end, do not modify the existing part else that will be not understandable for the readers

Answer (score -1):

Good evening,
I don't know if I understood your question right, but I will give it a try.
The problem is that you are checking if the args counter is 2, and the 2nd argument is a digit. if so, do the following code you have written. but if not?
You are not handling the case of argc==2 and argv[1] is not a digit.

Comment: Are you assuming it's evening everywhere? ;)

Comment: Are you assuming that I'm assuming its evening everywhere?
He said **Good evening**, I said Good evening back ;) @Ayxan

Comment: "*you are checking if the args counter is 2, and the 2nd argument is a digit*" : no, `argv[1]` is not the second argument but the first, `argv[0]` is not an argument of the program but the program. None of the elements in `argv` is a *digit/char* they are all an array of char then NULL. "*You are not handling the case of argc==2 and argv[1] is not a digit*" :  if you are speaking about the first char of `argv[1]` the OP does exactely that with `if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))`. Your answer is not an answer

Comment: hi @MajdRezik the question is that the program should not run if the user types the command and inside argv[1] there is a letter so lets say for example. ./caesar 5x if the user types x next to the key the program should not run and the Usage: ./caesar key must be displayed.